# Create a view based on a view on a different mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different `RDS mysql servers`....two different logins etc on aws.

How can I create a `view` in schema on `server 1` based on a view on a schema on `server 2`?  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to other server in a `view`, but you can set up [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) in such way that only some tables will be replicated from master (your `server 2`) to a slave (`server 1`). You can specify what tables to replicate with [--replicate-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table) option. Then you will be able to perform queries on replicated tables or create views with them. Tables will be synchronized between servers. Database replication may be a bit hard in understanding, but looks like it's the only way to achieve what you are up to.